# How to check in Swift if the user gave permission to access the photolibrary with UIImagePicker?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, image-gallery

I am currently working on an app that give the user a preview of the last the images he had taken with his camera, but I dont know how to check if the user gave permissions to access all the images in the gallery, selected images or he denied the access.

There is a method or class I can import to check the kind of permissions the user gave to my app?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below method to check the permission status for the gallery.
and if the permission is denied then also it navigates you to the app setting screen.

```
func checkGalleryPermission()
{
    let authStatus = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
    switch authStatus
    {
        case .denied : print("denied status")
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Photo library status is denied", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let cancelaction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default)
            let settingaction = UIAlertAction(title: "Setting", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default) { UIAlertAction in
                if let url = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: { _ in })
                }
            }
            alert.addAction(cancelaction)
            alert.addAction(settingaction)
            Viewcontoller.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            break
        case .authorized : print("success")
           //open gallery
            break
        case .restricted : print("user dont allowed")
            break
        case .notDetermined : PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ (newStatus) in
                if (newStatus == PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
                    print("permission granted")
                    //open gallery
                }
                else {
                    print("permission not granted")
                }
            })
            break
    case .limited:
       print("limited")
    @unknown default:
        break
    }
}
```